# Why does my JSON not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a little problem.
I have this JSON file

```
sprecherText = '[{"name" : "Ashwin","text":"Hi","image":"./images/char1.png"},{"name" : "Abhinandan","text":"Was geht?","image":"./images/char2.png"}]';
```

I parse it and I can use it nn my script.

```
var mydata = $.parseJSON(sprecherText);
```

But you see that the JSON is not good to read. So, I tried to break some lines like this.

```
sprecherText = 
'[{"name" : "Ashwin","text":"Hi","image":"./images/char1.png"},
{"name" : "Abhinandan","text":"Was geht?","image":"./images/char2.png"}]';
```

but, then I get this error

sprecherText is not defined

Then I tried to  make it different like this

```
{  
"sprecherText":[  
  {  
     "name":"Ashwin",
     "text":"Hi",
     "image":"./images/char1.png"
  },
  {  
     "name":"Abhinandan",
     "text":"Was geht?",
     "image":"./images/char2.png"
  }
]
}
```

I still get the error

sprecherText is not defined.

Someone have an idea why?

Comment: how you are loading your json file in your script where you are trying to parse?

Comment: @reza in the header i got this <script type="text/javascript" src="texteJSON.json"></script>

Comment: Since it is a different file I think you need to specify the filename. You can't just use `sprecherText`.

Comment: If it's an actual JSON file, it shouldn't have `sprecherText = '` and the trailing `'` in it. If you're loading it like a script, then you're really not needing JSON.

Comment: you got the answers below but next time just use jsonlint, or get a package with a sublime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are breaking a literal line without putting a backslach at the end `\`

```
var sprecherText = 
  '[{"name" : "Ashwin","text":"Hi","image":"./images/char1.png"},\
    {"name" : "Abhinandan","text":"Was geht?","image":"./images/char2.png"}]';

console.log(sprecherText)
'[{"name" : "Ashwin","text":"Hi","image":"./images/char1.png"},{"name" : "Abhinandan","text":"Was geht?","image":"./images/char2.png"}]'
```

Now this works

```
JSON.parse(sprecherText)
[ { name: 'Ashwin', text: 'Hi', image: './images/char1.png' },
  { name: 'Abhinandan',
    text: 'Was geht?',
    image: './images/char2.png' } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not working due to breaking a literal line in this example:

```
sprecherText = 
'[{"name" : "Ashwin","text":"Hi","image":"./images/char1.png"},
{"name" : "Abhinandan","text":"Was geht?","image":"./images/char2.png"}]';
```

turn it into the following and it will fix the issue:

```
var sprecherText = '[{"name" : "Ashwin","text":"Hi","image":"./images/char1.png"}, {"name" : "Abhinandan","text":"Was geht?","image":"./images/char2.png"}]';
```

In your final example of code your JSON is not actually valid as you are missing a closing `}` or you need to remove the first `{` to ensure it is valid.